# How to remove specific field from table in node js mongodb?

Tags: javascript

```
comment: 'hi'
replies: array
likes: array
```

I have to remove comment field and every time I delete it deletes the whole collections.
This is the code

```
deleteComment: async (root, { commentID, comment}) => {
    try{
        const deleteComment = await CommentModel.findOne(
            {_id:commentID}
        );
        if(deleteComment) {
            const remove = await CommentModel.deleteOne(comment)
            return(remove)
        }
    
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete by ID.

```
CommentModel.deleteOne({_id: new mongodb.ObjectID(commentID)});
```

I'm assuming you are using the `mongodb` npm package.